# Spotbugs configuration for multi project setup

Tags: java, gradle, spotbugs

I have a multi-project Gradle setup like so:

```
RootProject
    |
    ---- ProjectA
    |
    ---- ProjectB
    |
    ---- ProjectC
```

I want to apply SpotBugs to all my projects.

Doing the following in every project explicitly works.

For example, the following in `build.gradle` of `ProjectA`:

```
plugins {
  id 'com.github.spotbugs' version '1.6.9'
}

spotbugs {
    ignoreFailures = true
    effort = 'min'
    showProgress = true
    reportLevel = 'medium'
    // Only run spotbugs directly as too slow to run as CI.  
    // Will still run spotbugs when called like "gradlew spotbugsMain"
    sourceSets = []
}

tasks.withType(com.github.spotbugs.SpotBugsTask) {
  reports {
    xml.enabled = false
    html.enabled = true
  }
}
```

However, I do not want to duplicate this code in `build.gradle` files of all the projects.

How do I pull this out into the `RootProject`'s build file.

Example, inside the following block:

```
configure(subprojects.findAll {it.name != 'SomeProjectToIgnore'}) {
   // how to configure spotbugs here ?
}
```

Moving the block as is doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure spotbugs in root project's build.gradle the following way:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'maven repository url' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'gradle.plugin.com.github.spotbugs', name: 'spotbugs-gradle-plugin', version: '1.6.5'
    }
}

allprojects {

    apply plugin: 'com.github.spotbugs'

    dependencies {
        compileOnly group: 'com.github.spotbugs', name: 'spotbugs-annotations', version: '3.1.8'
        spotbugsPlugins group: 'com.h3xstream.findsecbugs', name: 'findsecbugs-plugin', version: '1.8.0'
    }

    spotbugs {
        toolVersion = '3.1.8'
        sourceSets = [ sourceSets.main ]
    }

}
```

Comment: * What went wrong:

> Could not find method compileOnly() for arguments [{group=com.github.spotbugs, name=spotbugs-annotations, version=3.1.8}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.